# Image sizes in Pygame are blowing up when I am running them from terminal; however in Spyder, it works fine

Tags: python, pygame

I have written a code to dynamically load and display images in one corner of my pygame display window. When I run it from Spyder, the code is working absolutely fine, the images are in proper size. However, when I am running the same from the terminal, the images are all out of proportions and going out of screen space.

[This is the screenshot of the window when I run the code from Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13hxH.jpg).

[This is the screenshot of the window when I run the code from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG4Bf.jpg)

I can't figure out any possible reason for the same. It's the same code every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for the same problem. It turns out that you have to transform the image to fit in the screen area. I suspect it is due to different versions of the python compilers in Spyder and terminal.

Use this: `img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (400, 300))`

where I have used img to name my image.